# how can I skip the asus account login page on an asus router

Tags: router

I bought an asus router and before it has access to the internet I need to change some settings but I am stuck at this page[image]
I can't login while the router is offline and I don't know how to skip this login.
How can I skip this login??

Answer (score 1):

[The internet](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/asus/rt-ac66u/login.htm) suggests that the default credentials for this device are **username: admin password:admin**.

Failing that, most routers have a sticker on them giving details of their default credentials.  Naturally, once you manage to log-in, you should change the admin password to something much more secure.